# GXT (Ext-GWT) + Pagination + HTTP GET

Tags: gwt, pagination, gxt

I'm trying to populate a GXT Grid using data retrieved from an online API (for instance, going to www.example.com/documents returns a JSON array of documents). In addition, I need to paginate the result.

I've read all the various blogs and tutorials, but most of them populate the pagination proxy using something like `TestData.GetDocuments()`. However, I want to get that info using HTTP GET.

I've managed to populate a grid, but without pagination, using a RequestBuilder + proxy + reader + loader. But it seems as though the actual loading of the data is "put off" until some hidden stage deep inside the GXT code. Pagination requires that data from the start, so I'm not sure what to do.

Can someone provide a simple code example which does what I need?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this going, here is what I did:

First I defined the proxy and loader for my data along with the paging toolbat:

```
private PagingModelMemoryProxy proxy;
private PagingLoader<PagingLoadResult<ModelData>> loader;
private PagingToolBar toolBar;
```

Next is the creation of each one, initializing with an empty ArrayList.

```
proxy = new PagingModelMemoryProxy(new ArrayList<EquipmentModel>());
loader = new BasePagingLoader<PagingLoadResult<ModelData>>(proxy);
loader.setRemoteSort(true);
toolBar = new PagingToolBar(100);
toolBar.bind(loader);
loader.load(0, 100);
```

Last, I have a set method in my view that gets called when the AJAX call is complete, but you could trigger it anywhere.  Here is my entire set method, Equipment and EquipmentModel are my database and view models respectively.

```
public void setEquipmentData(List<Equipment> data)
{
    Collections.sort(data);

    // build a list of models to be loaded
    List<EquipmentModel> models = new ArrayList<EquipmentModel>();

    for (Equipment equipment : data)
    {
        EquipmentModel model = new EquipmentModel(equipment);

        models.add(model);
    }

    // load the list of models into the proxy and reconfigure the grid to
    // refresh display.
    proxy.setData(models);

    ListStore<EquipmentModel> equipmentStore = new ListStore<EquipmentModel>(loader);

    equipmentGrid.reconfigure(equipmentStore, equipmentColumnModel);
    loader.load(0, 100);
}
```

The key here for me was re-creating the store with the same loader, the column model was pre-created and gets reused.